# How to map a NamedNativeQuery in a class that doesn't correspond to a single table

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

I've got a legacy SQL Server database, and they've given to me a query, which does some join between several tables.

> SELECT TipoDia, ServBus, Instante, Evento, [VistaHorariosActivos].Linea, Coche, [VistaHorariosActivos].Sublinea, [VistaHorariosActivos].Seccion, Punto, Tipo, Viaje, Operador, Fecha, [VistaHorariosActivos].Macro, Ruta, OrdenSeccion FROM [SAEBase].[dbo].[VistaHorariosActivos] INNER JOIN [SAEBase].[dbo].[LineaSublineaSeccionOrden] ON [VistaHorariosActivos].Macro = LineaSublineaSeccionOrden.Macro AND [VistaHorariosActivos].Linea = LineaSublineaSeccionOrden.Linea AND [VistaHorariosActivos].Sublinea = LineaSublineaSeccionOrden.Sublinea AND [VistaHorariosActivos].Seccion = LineaSublineaSeccionOrden.Seccion WHERE Fecha>:fecha AND VistaHorariosActivos.Macro=:macro AND VistaHorariosActivos.Linea=:linea AND (Evento = 1 OR Evento = 5)

I want to map these results into a java class (TripDTO): I've got every column mapped with their proper data type.

The issue is that I don't know whether the TripDTO class should have the @Entity and @table annotations. Actually, that query isn't related to a single table.

Can somebody help me out defining that class?

Here you are the code:

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "getTripDtos",
        query = "<<the query>>",
        resultClass = TripDTO.class
    )   
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "???")
public class TripDTO implements Serializable {

    /*
     * Atributos 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5719572417390931185L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Macro", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "usertype.IdMacroUserType")
    private Short macro;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Linea", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Short linea;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Sublinea", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Byte sublinea;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Seccion", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "usertype.IdSeccionUserType")
    private Integer seccion;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Punto", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer punto;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Instante", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer instante;

    @Column(name = "TipoDia", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "usertype.TipoDiaUserType")
    private String tipoDia;
    @Type(type = "usertype.ServicioBusUserType")
    @Column(name = "ServBus", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer servBus;
    @Column(name = "Evento", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "usertype.TipoEventoUserType")
    private Short evento;
    @Column(name = "Coche", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Byte coche;
    @Column(name = "Tipo", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "usertype.TipoNodoUserType")
    private Short tipo;
    @Column(name = "Viaje", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer viaje;
    @Column(name = "Operador", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String operador;
    @Column(name = "Fecha", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime fecha;
    @Column(name = "Ruta", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer ruta;
    @Column(name = "OrdenSeccion", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer ordenSeccion;
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have a named query and you want to map it to a result class (always an entity), you **must** annotate it with the `@Entity` annotation.
You arent obliged to annotate it with `@Table` but hibernate (jpa in general) needs to know that this class is an entity. You also dont have to annotate your field with `@Column` since you are just using a dto and not a persisted table row (your entity isnt referencing a specific table in DB).

Having done the annotation, you can use the `resultClass` property where you define your dto `@Entity` annotated class. 
This class **must** have all fields corresponding to the output columns of your query. So if, for example one column is `Orden_Seccion`, this should be exactly the field name of the dto class.

You can use [resultMappings](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/SqlResultSetMapping) too but I think, as I see from your query, that `resultClass` is good and clean for your situation.

Comment: I managed to give a solution to that particular case. Now I want to use your solution in another part of the project, but with no luck. I've created a class with two single attrs, who is annotated with NamedNativeQueries, NamedNativeQuery inside it and Entity. I've added the entity to the configuration of hibernate, but it throws an exception: Building SessionFactory failed. org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: model.ViajeDTO

Comment: yes, every entity needs an id, a property that has to be annotated as its... primary key (with `@Id` annotation), even though it isnt mapped to a real table.

Comment: an id can be a single field or a combination of fields (composite key).

Comment: I've added an Id, and it throws me another exception... Building SessionFactory failed. org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [ViajeDTO]

Comment: (at)NamedNativeQueries({
 (at)NamedNativeQuery(
  name = "getViajesPasajerosParada",
  query = "SELECT [Viaje] AS id, COUNT([Viaje]) AS cantidad FROM [dbo].[PasajerosParada] WHERE [Fecha]>=:fecha AND [Macro]=:macro AND [Linea]=:linea AND ([Parada]=:origen OR [Parada]=:destino) GROUP BY [Viaje]",
  resultClass = ViajeDTO.class
 )
})
(at)Entity
public class ViajeDTO{

 /*
  * Atributos 
  */
 @Id
 private Integer unique;
 
 private Short id;
 private Integer cantidad;

Comment: it doesnt seem that this is the problem, since you havent annotated your class with `@Table`. anywhere else that you  might be using this entity?

Comment: Nowhere else... Anyway I came up with another solution. Thanks @Apostolos for your kind help :)

Comment: can you post your solution since you unchecked my answer so as other people to be helped?